# Issue with StructureMapController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

When ever my project is run in debug mode on a local machine, I get the following error `Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: key`. I've tried to debug it to see whats causing the issue but I've had very little luck. When ever a view is requested this error is thrown but the page loads, I'm at loss at what is causing this issue.

I've included the the error message and stack trace below:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=key
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ContainsKey(TKey key)
       at StructureMap.Util.Cache`2.get_Item(KEY key)
       at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType)
       at StructureMap.Container.GetInstance(Type pluginType)
       at StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance(Type pluginType)
       at MvcContrib.StructureMap.StructureMapControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext context, String controllerName) in c:\builds\mvccontrib\src\MvcContrib.StructureMap\StructureMapControllerFactory.cs:line 13
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that any CSS or JavaScript resources that are referenced on your page actually do exist at the locations specified.  If the resource is not found, your `StructureMapControllerFactory` may attempt to get an instance of a controller that matches the route.

If your `StructureMapControllerFactory` looks something like this:

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
        RequestContext requestContext, 
        Type controllerType)
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as Controller;
    }
}
```

then you can inspect the `requestContext.RouteData.Values` to help identify which resource is causing the problem.

Comment: turns out to have been a issue with a missing favicon. Thanks for the answer, I'm still learning how to debug structure map projects.